# File Compression Type changes when converting image to base64

Tags: c#, base64

I have and image with a compression type of CCITT T.6 which is converted to base64 and sent to a backend API, where base64 string will be converted back to the original image and validate the file details. My problem is whenI convert the base64 string back to its original image, the compression type for the image has now changed to LZW. Does converting an image to a base64 string change its compression type? If so how can I keep the files original compression type.

```
string img = "";       
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filepath))
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        img = base64String;
    }
}

LoadImage(img);

 public void LoadImage(string base64image)
 {
     byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64image);
     Image image;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
     {
         image = Image.FromStream(ms);
     }
     File.WriteAllBytes(filepath,bytes);
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the (web)server is accepting LZW? So the client compresses the upload? Something like that i guess

Comment: This does not appear to be your actual code. What's that `File.WriteAllBytes()` doing there? You don't seem to be doing anything with `image` after loading from the stream. --- And no, converting to/from Base64 will not by itself change the compression method of the image.

Comment: ah sorry the File.WriteAllBytes() was for me to save the image and check the actual file details through file explorer. My actual code will return the image and do some validation on the file details.

Comment: The base64 conversion surely doesn't change the image format. I would look at your first method, you are loading the image and saving to a memorystream. Why not return `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath))`?

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the memory stream and using `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath))` suggested by Steeeve seems to have solved the problem. Image Compression types are now consistent after regenerating the image from a base64 string.